# sum of a field in mongodb using php yii2 ex

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, yii2

I am using mongodb extension for yii2. I want to get the sum of a field `total` from mongodb collection.

```
$query = new Query;
$rows = $query->select(['total'])->from('invoices')->where(['status' => 'Unpaid'])->sum('total');
```

But, I am getting zero every time, even though it is greater than zero. Is there any issue with my query?

Comment: Hi,
I too have the same issue while using aggregate function in mongo db query. I have went through internet and tried different methods but I count n't find a solution. Please reply...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always be able to access the [collection object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html) and perform an [aggregation operation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html#aggregate()-detail) on this. All of this basically follows the standard [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) syntax:

```php
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('invoices');
$result = $collection->aggregate(
    array( '$match' => array( 'status' => 'Unpaid' ) ),
    array( '$group' => array(
        '_id' => NULL,
        'total' => array( '$sum' => '$total' )
    ))
);
```

Most higher level frameworks have a way of accessing the native driver objects where the operations are basically the same, and more efficient than abstractions offered, particularly by anything attempting to bridge the SQL and NoSQL worlds.

Bridging is a good thing in general, but it is never optimal since both technologies work very differently.